# Exporting Geodatabase with Subtypes and Domains to Microsoft Access Without Losing Information?

Tags: file-geodatabase, domains, ms-access, subtype

I want to export a geodatabase file with all subtypes and domains values to open in Microsoft Access without losing any information.

Comment: What type of geodatabase? Personal, file, enterprise (SQL Server, Oracle)?

Comment: The concept of subtypes is a geodatabase specific concept, and there is no equivalent in MS Access. The Domain concept will have look-up tables as the equivalent concept in MS Access. You can create the look-up table by using the Domain to table gp tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create an empty Personal Geodatabase (`*.mdb`; an Access database) and then copy/paste feature classes from a File Geodatabase (`*.gdb`) into it.

There will be limits to what you can see in it using MS Access.